# Muffin Builder has a limit? (Wordpress - Be Theme)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

a couple of days ago i downloaded the Wordpress's theme called BeTheme. It's a nice theme that use a plugin called "Muffin Builder", this allows you to build your site in a easier way.
It worked all fine, but when i started to make a site, with the muffin builder, that has a lot of content i had a little problem.

The problem is that when i try to add one more element, and upload the site, the last content that i tried to add it dissapears. So i did a lot of tests, and i have a theory that maybe this plugin has a limit of content, or maybe the betheme has a limit of height that the website can show you.

Do you know if that is correct? There is a way to change the limit of the builder?

Comment: Add link to theme and plugin. What tests did you do? What limit of heigth? Can you provide any code?

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/betheme-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7758048
That is the theme, that it cames with the plugin Muffin Builder. And i cant provide code because i working with localhosting . 
There is no code, becuase the plugin uses a visuals tools.
And the tests that i made basically were, adding more elements in so many ways, a couple of times, but its like the last element that i try to add dissapears when i refresh the website.

Comment: Well there's your problem: nothing from themeforest can be relied upon....

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation on your hosting side, but the theme, while pretty good (i use it for like 40-50% of my WP sites) does have limitations in the muffin/visual builder; specifically when you add too many component parts on page. Even the best hosts, like flywheel and wpengine will still have this problem after a certain size is reached.. You can "adjust it" one of two ways: use less rows or stack more into the rows and not have a separate container for each which will allow you to cram just a few more items in... or you can adjust the max input vars on the server side like so (most hosts don't give access to this but will accommodate):

php_value max_input_vars 10000 (this is a larger amount than you have currently)

A lot of hosts, particularly shared hosting environments limit this to 1000 or 3000 vars. Some hosts allow you to increase it through the ftp panel and/or through the htacces file though, if you do not know what you are doing: DO NOT ATTEMPT. NEVER mess with the HTACCESS unless you are well versed in the functional nature of the files which compose a wordpress install (or any platform for that matter). Good Luck!

Start by calling your hosting company and ensuring you have the highest PHP that is stable, and by requesting the higher level of adjustment to the max vars on server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a website in a mag section which I am developing offline. The max input variable was limited by host. The default value for the input variable was 1000 which I was getting no more than 9 sections per page, and sometimes more or less sections, because of the length factor. 
Here is how I resolved the issue:

The solution is to add 3 files named:

1. "php.ini"
2. "php5.ini"
3. ".user.ini " (do not forget to mention DOT USER DOT INI)

In both 1. root of website and in the 2. wp-admin folder.

Write this code on all 3 above mentioned files:

```
max_input_vars = 3000
suhosin.get.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
```